# How to make specific binary from specific object file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is my makefile, i have object files in obj/ directory, and i need to compile them into binaries in bin/ folder, but somehow it doesn't work as i wanted it to work, any ideas?

```
SOURCES= $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS:= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS:= $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJECTS))
NAMES:= $(patsubst %.c, %, $(SOURCES))
NAMES:= $(addprefix bin/,$(NAMES))
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -o
DIRS = bin obj

all: $(DIRS) $(NAMES)

$(NAMES): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(DIRS)
```

Actual output:

```
mkdir -p bin
mkdir -p obj
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task1.o task1.c
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task2.o task2.c
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task3.o task3.c
gcc -o bin/task1 obj/task1.o
gcc -o bin/task2 obj/task1.o
gcc -o bin/task3 obj/task1.o
```

Expected output:

```
mkdir -p bin
mkdir -p obj
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task1.o task1.c
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task2.o task2.c
gcc -Wall -c -o obj/task3.o task3.c
gcc -o bin/task1 obj/task1.o
gcc -o bin/task2 obj/task2.o
gcc -o bin/task3 obj/task3.o
```

Comment: Am I blind? This looks like your actual and expected outputs were identical....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this rule:

```
$(NAMES): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

*each* executable depends on *all* objects. And since `$<` grabs only the first prerequisite, all you see is `obj/task1.o`.

Do it this way:

```
bin/%: obj/%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

or this way:

```
$(NAMES): bin/% : obj/%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply but any of that doesn't work, on first way i got: 

Huge amount of lines like "(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here" 

and on second:

"gcc -o bin/task1 
gcc: no input files"

Comment: Hello there again =) Now everything works, thanks a lot, if you notice you helped second time =) but if you don't mind can you explain how is that i can't write "$(NAMES): obj/%.o" (actually i can but it gives me "there isn't rule for blahblahblah") $(NAMES) consists of bin/<filename>, why should i write it directly? bin/%, are there any method to write symbol "%" into the $(NAMES)? maybe something like $(%NAMES),or give me a link (please, any link except GNU makefile manual(my english still isn't good enough to freely read it without vocabulary)